# Setting width to 100% but height to be default

Tags: html, css

I wish to change the width of a pic to 100%. But don't want the height specified or affecting the width anyway and causing the image to distort.

What is the term to null/zero a height. I have been using  /* height: 68px; */ as a fix in the stylesheet for now. But there must be a better way?

Before

```
height: 68px;
width: 482px;
```

After
    /* height: 68px; */
    width:100%

Comment: height:auto? or if you want any fix size(not more then) then min-height? please come with example or little bit more details..Thanx

Comment: @LeotheLion did you mean max-height? Also ser my comment to Sydney answer to see what you need when using max-height

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height from the image all together and if the image inherits a height you can reset this using `height: auto;` also make sure to not forget resetting the `min-height` and `max-height` properties to `auto` if these are inherited / set.

The reason this works is because images maintain aspect ratio automatically so if you set a height only, the width will auto-adjust, if you set the width only, the height will auto adjust.

That's pretty much all there is to it!

Also - if you're looking for more advanced image effects I'd recommend replacing the image tag with a div containing the `background-image` property - it will allow you to be flexible in different ways such as allowing an image to scale until it covers the entire background (`background-size: cover;`) or to scale to whatever is possible (`background-size: contain`).

Good luck!

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh isn't it possible to give "max-height"? or for an image you shouldn't use that?

Comment: @RicardoAlves you've commented on the wrong answer I think man but yeah ofcourse you can give `max-height` to an image - without any problems. It basically just acts as a constraint in that case which is what `background-size: contain` would do for a `background-image` but that would include a `max-width` too just so that the image cannot exceed the bounds of the element / specified height / specified width :)

Comment: ok, thanks for the detailed answer. I did commented on the right question, just got the user name wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the height property from the css, for the image, and it should work. You cal also set image height to auto.